# failure to send email by SendInBlue

Tags: scala, email, sendinblue

i'm using SendInBlue Java Api to send email, i write this code en scala:

```
object SendInBlueApi extends App{
  val http : Sendinblue= new Sendinblue("https://api.sendinblue.com/v2.0","API_KEY");
  var data: Map[String, Any]= Map[String, Any]()
  data += ("to" -> "test1@gmail.com")
  data += ("from" -> "test2@gmail.com")
  data += ("subject" -> "My subject")
  data += ("text" -> "This is text")
  val str = http.send_email(data)
  println(str.toString)
}
```

but i get this error: 
{"code":"failure","message":"valid 'to' email address required","data":[]}

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of adding elements in a map:

```
object SendInBlueApi extends App{
  val http : Sendinblue= new Sendinblue("https://api.sendinblue.com/v2.0","API_KEY");
  var data: Map[String, Any] = Map[String, Any](
    data("to") -> "test1@gmail.com",
    data("from") -> "test2@gmail.com",
    data("subject") -> "My subject",
    data("text") -> "This is text"
  )
        println(str.toString)
}
```

Comment: i don't think so, i try it but i get the error Error:(20, 3) value update is not a member of Map[String,Any]
  data("to") ="test1@gmail.com"

Comment: @salma1 I updated the answer, let me know if that works!

Comment: no, it didn't work , i get the error Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: to

Comment: @salma1 in wich part of the code? did you try to debug de map and see if it has the value? print them or some?